# iPhone doesn't connect to the web socket but the simulator does

Tags: swift, sockets, https, websocket

Physical devices cannot connect to my web socket. I tried it with 3 different phone and with different networks. It works fine with my simulators though. I am not getting an error message apart from the standard "Cannot connect to the server" from socket.io on the client.

I don't know if this is a valid indicator but I also tried using https://www.websocket.org/ with the following parameter:

wss://converzone.htl-perg.ac.at:5134

I am getting a "ERROR: undefined DISCONNECTED" there.

I am using an ubuntu server which runs Ubuntu 16.04. The web socket is from socket.io and I am coding with Swift on the client and with Node.js on the server. This whole thing is running on my school's server.

```
// Here is an array of all connections to the server
var connections = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

function newConnection(socket) {

    console.log(socket.id + " connected.");

    socket.on('add-user', function(user) {

              connections[user.id] = {
              "socket": socket.id
              };

              });

    socket.on('chat-message', function(message) {

              console.log(message);

              if (connections[message.receiver]) {

              console.log("Send to: " + connections[message.receiver].socket);
              //io.sockets.connected[connections[message.receiver].socket].emit("chat-message", message);

              io.to(connections[message.receiver].socket).emit('chat-message', message);

              } else {
              console.log("Send push notification")
              sendPushNotificationToIOS(message.senderName, message, message.deviceToken, message.sound)
              }
              });

    //Removing the socket on disconnect
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
              console.log("The client disconnected");
              console.log("The new list of clients is: " + connections)
              for (var id in connections) {
              if (connections[id].socket === socket.id) {
              delete connections[id];
              break;
              }
              }
              })
}
```

Please understand that this problem seems very weird to me. I have changed the AppTransferProtocol in my plist and changed the port from 3000 to 5134. Nothing changed. Tell me what code would seem relevant apart from the (minimal) server code.

Comment: While the server converzone.htl-perg.ac.at is accessible on port 443 (https) from the internet it is  currently not accessible on port 5134. Could it be that you try with your simulator from inside the local network (or some VPN) where this port is accessible but fail to connect when the iPhone connects from outside since the port is blocked by a firewall?

Comment: Oh yes you are right! I have never noticed it since I have setup my computer to turn on the vpn automatically. Now that I have disabled it it doesn't work the simulator. So my question, how can I disable the firewall for this port?

Comment: *"how can I disable the firewall for this port?"* - This fully depends on your unknown network architecture and where exactly the blocking is done. If there is an IT department managing the infrastructure you likely need to contact these.

Comment: I see, the disabling of the firewall on my server alone won't bring anything. Since my server is just a virtual machine running on the school server

Comment: Thank you. I asked the it team and they enabled the port